# Java : with respect to Ternary Operator for this requirement

Tags: java

```
<Student>
<number>122</number>
<CVF>PG</CVF>
</Student>

class Student 
{
char grade 
}
```

**Now , i need to set the grade value for the Student Object above by parsing the XML Above**

This CVF Element in XML  can have two values either PG or MQ

As per the business , If it is PG then its value should be 1 or else 0

I defined in this way .

```
Student.grade = (attribute.getValue().toString()=="PG"?'1' : '0');
```

Please let me know if any better code will be suitable for the above requirement ??

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

1. I don't know what XML library you are using, but <CVF> is not an attribute. But let's assume `attribute.getValue()` is correct.
2. If `attribute.getValue()` returns a string, there is no reason to call `toString()`.
3. Use `equals()` not == when comparing `Strings`, unless you know they are interned.
4. You don't write `Student.grade` unless it's a static field.  You have a variable of type
   `Student` with a name, say `s`, and then you can say `s.grade`.
5. If the input has not been validated, you might want to drop the ternary operator and do something like:

```
Student s = ...
String val = attribute.getValue().toString();
if ("PG".equals(val)) {
    s.grade = '1';
}
else if ("MQ".equals(val)) {
    s.grade = '0';
}
else {
    throw new RuntimeException("illegal value for CVF: " + val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming grade defined as char.

Student.grade = ("PG".equals(attribute.getValue().toString())?'1' : '0');

Comment: Its better to check String first and then value to avoid NullPointerException.

Comment: Agree. I am in process of editing answer while you are commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Dont compare Strings with "=". Its always better to do this instead.

Student.grade = ("PG".equals(attribute.getValue().toString()))?'1' : '0';